# Extracting scaling factor and rotation angle from TransformationFunction

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation, rotation, geometric-transform, scaling

I have successfully transformed two 2D data sets (`data1`, `data2`) by using `FindGeometricTransform`:

```
tr = FindGeometricTransform[data1, data2, TransformationClass -> "Similarity"]
```

`"Similarity"` considers translation, rotation and scaling.

As a result, I get the following:

[image: result]

The translation is contained in the last column:

```
xTranslation = tr[[2, 1, 1, 3]]

-9.49427

yTranslation = tr[[2, 1, 2, 3]]

-13.1009
```

**How can I find the rotation angle and scaling factor from the resulting transformation matrix** `{1.00748,0.00926369},{-0.00926369,1.00748}}`? Is *Mathematica*  storing the information about the rotation and scaling matrices somewhere, and not only showing the result of the matrix multiplication?

Comment: `Take[tr[[2, 1]], 2, 2]`?

Comment: @J. M: Thank you. What do you think about my last sentence of the question: Is mathematica somewhere storing the information about the rotation and sclaing matrices and not only showing the result of the matrix multiplication?

Comment: The function already composes the transformations; you'll need to do extra linear algebra (e.g. w/ `QRDecomposition[]`) to separate them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To demonstrate my suggestion in the comments, let's randomly generate the composition of a scaling, a rotation, and a translation, and apply it to a list of known points:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1467827]; (* for reproducibility *)
            rot = RotationMatrix[RandomReal[2 π]];
            sca = DiagonalMatrix[{#, #} & @ RandomReal[3]];
            tr = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2]];

pts = {{88, 59}, {96, 11}, {66, 2}, {54, 62}};
new = AffineTransform[{rot.sca, tr}][pts];
```

Use `FindGeometricTransform[]` to determine the `TransformationFunction[]`:

```
{err, tf} = FindGeometricTransform[pts, new, TransformationClass -> "Similarity"];
```

The first thing to do to recover the parameters from the `TransformationFunction[]` is to use `TransformationMatrix[]` to obtain the associated homogeneous matrix:

```
tm = TransformationMatrix[tf]
   {{0.221083, 0.272837, 0.0193194}, {-0.272837, 0.221083, 0.426155}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

We can easily get the translation vector from `tm`:

```
v = tm[[1 ;; -2, -1]]
   {0.0193194, 0.426155}
```

Now, for the linear algebra. Apply the QR decomposition on the leading submatrix corresponding to the composed rotation and scaling:

```
{q, r} = QRDecomposition[tm[[;; -2, ;; -2]]]
   {{{-0.629568, 0.776946}, {0.776946, 0.629568}}, {{-0.351166, 0.}, {0., 0.351166}}}
```

Note that the `r` factor is diagonal, which indicates a genuine scaling transformation. Had the off-diagonal entry been nonzero, this is an indication that the two sets of points are not related by a scaling transformation, and you have more work to do.

In any event, the diagonal elements are not all positive, but we can perform a normalization so that we have a genuine scaling matrix:

```
di = DiagonalMatrix[Sign[Diagonal[r]]];
sc = Diagonal[di.r]
   {0.351166, 0.351166}
```

Finally, let's get the angle of the rotation matrix:

```
θ = ArcTan @@ First[di.q]
   -0.8898
```

We now have all the needed parameters. Let's do a few checks:

```
Max[Norm /@ (AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[θ].ScalingMatrix[sc], v}][new] - pts)]
   2.92964*10^-14

Norm[TransformationMatrix[Composition[
                          AffineTransform[{rot.sca, tr}], 
                          AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[θ].ScalingMatrix[sc], v}]]] -
     IdentityMatrix[3]]
   3.01074*10^-14
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution